# Forgot password email: wrong shop view in link

Tags: customer, ce-1.9.0.1, email-templates

I have two shop views and both use the same user accounts. If an user registers to shop A and requests a password reset in shop B, he gets a link to shop A.

In the email template this link is created with:

```
{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}
```

I would like the email to link to the shop it is send from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think happens is that in the email send function `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail` the store id attached to the loaded user is used and not the current store you are on.

```
public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
{
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
    }

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

If the customer has been created via the admin the store id here will be the current websites' default store id.

What you would need to do is change this function to use the current store id rather than the one attached to the user, but I am sure this was done for a purpose though I do not know what that is.

The "simplest" way of doing this would be to change the line `$storeId = $this->getStoreId();` to be `$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();`

**Note: This happens across a lot of the emails that are sent to the customer**

Comment: I just found this function myself and this did work (added my fix). I will keep an eye on possible side effects and report back if I find any...

Comment: cool, there are more functions in the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` that do this sort of thing

Comment: Is this really the problem? If the user exists two times it looks to me like Magento finds the wrong user for the password request function?

Comment: @DavidManners good point! The same happens in `sendNewAccountEmail()` and `sendPasswordReminderEmail()`. But the first is always in the correct shop and the other one is not used in my case. So I think this is fine.

Comment: @Alex I am not really sure why this is done this way but the email address is unique on website level. I guess it is done to send the email to the user in the language/store they are registered against